# Check if Java (or any applications) installed in Windows

Tags: java, windows, shell

I want to provide software which runs on Java. For the software I also would like to provide something which allows users to see if their machine already has Java installed.

It should be like this if it is in macOS

```
#!/bin/sh
command -v java
```

How can I achieve what I want?
what environment should I use?
Windows batch ? or..

Comment: you can run java -version in bat file and check

Comment: thank you I also use registry as suggested by @LinuX Man.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose your program needs to be RUN with Java, it's cleared you meant about JRE.

[image: Default registry for Java Runtime Environment]

Just check in the Registry if the `CurrentVersion` exists as shown.
[image: Registry Values]

You may use this way to read the Registry (JAVA code): [Read/write to Windows registry using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62289/read-write-to-windows-registry-using-java)

If the registry value returns, then JRE installed.